# Is there an efficient and free method of migrating a 6GB Interbase DB to MySql?

Tags: mysql, migration, interbase

That's about it.  I can always just dump it to csv and read it in, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Why avoid it?  It's probably faster than anything else going.  MySQL Loader is REALLY fast.  What problems do you foresee?

Comment: "What problems do you foresee?" Taking a long time.  But I guess you're right: dump it out, kick off the load, and work on other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Since both Interbase and MySql have ODBC drivers, how about using your favorite development environment to write an app that opens each table in the IB database and copies it into the MySql database?  There are various languages and IDE's that support data access using odbc.

This would be nicer than using csv because your code could copy the schema during the process of copying each table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com)

> Cross database development
>
> Use the Schema Compare and Migration
>   Tools to compare testing and deployed
>   databases, migrate existing databases
>   to different database systems.

ps: I don't know why you want to migrate from Interbase to MySQL but you can also take a look to Firebird